# Ритчи, Керниган "Язык программирования С 3 издание" указывают main() без типа, это не ошибка?

Tags: c, книги

Всем привет, начал изучать `С` по данной книге и появилось сомнение в дальнейшем обучение по данной книге. 
Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main() 
{ 
    printf ("здравствуй, мир\n"); 
}
```

На сколько помню в `С` и плюсах всегда главная функция указывалась с типом, который она будет возвращать, либо не будет. Соответственно `int main()` или `void main()`, так же встречал и с аргументом `int main(void)`. Теперь вопрос, стоит ли мне дальше изучать по данной книге язык или же не стоит тратить время? Меня берёт сомнения, в правильности изложения в данной книге.

Comment: Какого года издания книга? Как бы вам сказать... Просто язык эволюционирует. Аналог - вопрос, стоит ли изучать русский язык по учебнику XVIII века? Так сказать, вотще надеяться, что архаизмы в языке будут спопешествовать пониманию оного. Т.е. я бы все же искал книгу поновее, по C99. Хотя обратная совместимость и должна вытягивать такие программы, но, как по мне, лучше все же сразу учиться с учетом последних стандартов... *"По-моему, так." (с) Пух*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У книги "Язык программирования С" только два издания. При этом второе издание вышло незадолго до выхода первого стандарта языка С - С89/90 - и содержало ряд несоответствий с ним. Потом оно было задним числом приведено в соответствие с этим стандартом. "Третьим изданием", однако, исправленный вариант назвать не принято.

В первом стандарте языка С еще существовало правило "неявного `int`", которое разрешало опускать тип `int` в объявлениях. Так что нет ничего необычного в том, что вы увидели объявление с "неявным int" в этой книге. Начиная со стандарта C99 такие объявления в языке С запрещены. То есть это устаревшая конструкция.

Книга "Язык программирования С" Кергигана и Ритчи представляет историческую ценность, но для изучения языка она малопригодна.

---

**P.S.** Даже в C89/90, в котором существовало правило "неявного int", полностью опускать все *declaration-specifiers* разрешалось только в *определении* функции. То есть

```
main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

было легальным. Но вот просто объявление функции как

```
foo();
```

легальным не являлось. Можно

```
const foo();
// или
static foo();
```

но не просто `foo()`.

Comment: По какой же тогда книге мне лучше учить язык, желательно с99?

Comment: @B1aZe, есть книга Modern C.

Comment: Про «только историческую ценность» не соглашусь. Издание с _ANSI C_ вполне подходит на роль учебника _языка._ А вот учебников _практики_ программирования на _C,_ с учётом отладки, динамического, и статического анализа видеть ещё не приходилось.

Answer (score 2):

[Керниган-Ритчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)) - маст рид. Ритчи является собственно одним из авторов языка. Это первоисточник, который позволяет посмотреть на язык Си так как он задумывался авторами - без поздних наслоений и придумок криворучек.

Безусловно, с тех пор язык сильно изменился в сторону более жесткой типизации.

Касательно собственно самого кода:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
main() 
{ 
    printf ("здравствуй, мир\n"); 
}
```

Во времена Кернигана-Ритчи в стандарте Unix (для которого и был написан Си) предполагалось по умолчанию, что любая программа должна возвращать `exit code` при этом код `0` трактовался как успешное завершение программы, любое другое значение предполагало ошибку во время выполнения, соответственно предполагалось само собой разумеющимся что `main()` (как точка входа) по завершению должен возвращать некое целочисленное значение, то есть для юниксоида (целевого читателя книжки Кернигана-Ритчи) - это было естественным предположение неявного `int`.

До сих пор разбирая старые исходники каких-нибудь GNU alike проектов, можно встретить этот неявный `int`.

Как то так.

Answer (score 0):

Если продолжите читать дальше, то узнаете, что в `C` конструкции `main()` и `int main()` - эквивалентны. А также эквивалентны конструкции `... main()` и `... main(void)`.

Безусловно стоит продолжать чтение, потому что не зная таких нюансов можно потом очень долго удивляться, как же оно скомпилировалось?

Comment: Грубо неправильно.  Объявления `main()` и `main(void)` в С не эквивалентны и никогда эквивалентными не были.

Comment: @AnT, уточните, пожалуйста, чему в полной нотации эквивалентны пустые скобки при объявлении функции, если не void

Comment: @ГерманБорисов а не функции ли с переменным числом аргументов?

Comment: @pavel, у функции с переменным числом аргументом должен быть хотя бы один явный параметр, за которым стоит многоточие. Во всяком случае в древних версиях языка.

Comment: Объявление c `()` является устаревшим объявлением в стиле K&R. Оно объявляет функцию с *неуказанным* количеством параметров. С точки зрения определения (т.е. тела) функции у такой функции нет параметров. Однако с точки зрения внешнего мира у такой функции неизвестное число параметров. Другими словами, объявления функций с `()` не являются *прототипами*. Такие объявления (как и все объявления в стиле K&R) являются obsolescent, т.е. подлежат удалению из языка в будущем. Функция без параметров в С объявляется как `(void)` и именно как `(void)`. Объявление с `(void)` является прототипом.